# How to make a reverse foreach search in velocity script?

Tags: velocity, marketo

Marketo has a limit of 10 most recent opportunities that are searchable, and unfortunately we have a good number of users with more than 10 opportunities.

It appears the foreach loop starts at the least recently updated opportunity, and works its way up the list to the most recently update opportunity. The issue here is that when they have more than 10, the script can't access those opportunities that are the most recently updated. We could get around this by reversing the order the script searches the opportunity list (by reversing the foreach).

This is is the setup we have now (the script looks for a set of conditions within an opportunity, if it doesn't find them it looks for a different set, and so on).

```
#set($stip_guid = ${StipList.get(0).stip_opp_guid})

#foreach($opportunity in $OpportunityList)
#if($opportunity.o_opportunity_guid == $stip_guid && $opportunity.o_clear_to_close_date)
Display Unique Copy A
#break
#elseif($opportunity.o_opportunity_guid == $stip_guid && $opportunity.o_sent_to_underwriting)
Display Unique Copy B
#break
#elseif($opportunity.o_opportunity_guid == $stip_guid && $opportunity.o_processing_received)
Display Unique Copy C
#break
#else
Default Copy 
#break#end#end
```

Comment: I don't know the syntax of this language, but if it allows, good indentation makes your code more comprehensible and thus it results better answers for you. Anyways, your question seems to have a quite good quality, welcome on the SO and good luck here!

Comment: I agree, and thanks for the warm welcome! There is a strange issue with text versions however - in the standard HTML email indentation works fine, but in the text only version marketo translates the indentations as text spaces. I am fairly new to velocity, so perhaps there is something I am missing to combat that, but the only way I have found is to remove indentations once I have finished a scipt...

Answer (score 2):

Marketo doesn't seem to be providing a tool which would reverse a collection.

But why not look on indices rather than on objects themselves?

```
#set($max = $opportunityList.size() - 1)
#foreach($i in [ $max ..  0 ])
  #set($opportunity = $opportunityList[$i])
  ...
#end
```

Comment: I'll give this a shot! Thanks so much for your reply. I am new to velocity, and there is a very scarce amount of documentation on velocity scripting for marketo - forums and websites like stack overflow are a god send